# What's the best way create a pyramid-like html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table like this:

```
     A  B 
   C  D  E
```

In which case each line is centered and the cells are evenly distributed.

I'm currently using nested tables but feel that's not the best solution. Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a single table:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td 
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">E</td><td colspan="2">F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a use for tables use the `colspan` attribute on the `td` like below

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="3">A</td>
         <td colspan="3">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="2">C</td>
         <td colspan="2">D</td>
         <td colspan="2">E</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Remember tables are for displaying data not for layout.

Hope this helps.